# How to return a max and min of a random number gen in C#

Tags: c#

```
Random number = new Random();
int n;

for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
    n = number.Next(0,1000);
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

I need to figure out how to return the range, max and min values of
the random numbers. I am not allowed to use arrays. Could you please also explain how you got to the answer.

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried? You'll need some variables to keep track of things as you generate the numbers...

Comment: @zeroef http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

```
Random number = new Random();
int min = int.MaxValue,
    max = int.MinValue;

for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
    int n = number.Next(0, 1000);
    Console.WriteLine(n);

    if (n < min)
        min = n;
    if (n > max)
        max = n;
}

int range = min - max + 1;
Console.WriteLine("Min = {0}, Max = {1}, Range = {2}", min, max, range);
```

Comment: Though all answers are valid, your's is the only one who actually answered the question fully, by actually working out the "range". May I suggest though that you make the range `int range = max - min;` instead of `int range = min - max + 1;`?

Answer (score 1):

You could get all O-O and Linqy about it. First, build your accumulator class:

```
class Accumulator
{

  public Accumulator Add( int n )
  {
    min = min.HasValue && min.Value < n ? min.Value : n ;
    max = max.HasValue && max.Value > n ? max.Value : n ;
    return this ;
  }

  private int? min = null ;
  private int? max = null ;

  public int Min { get { return min.Value     ; } }
  public int Max { get { return max.Value     ; } }
  public int Range { get { return (Max-Min)+1 ; } }

  public override string  ToString()
  {
    return string.Format( "Min:{0}, Max:{1}, Range:{2}" , Min , Max , Range ) ;
  }

}
```

Then it's an easy incantation:

```
Random random = new Random() ;
Accumulator summary = Enumerable.Range( 1 , 100 )
                                .Aggregate( new Accumulator() ,
                                  (acc,n) => acc.Add(random.Next(0,1000))
                                ) ;
Console.WriteLine( summary ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple, just keep track of the min and max at each step:

```
Random number = new Random();
int min = int.MaxValue, max = int.MinValue;
for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
    int n = number.Next(0,1000);
    min = Math.Min(min, n);
    max = Math.Max(max, n);
}

Console.WriteLine(min);
Console.WriteLine(max);
```

Comment: I prefer Jon Skeet's approach to answering obvious homework questions.

Comment: What does that mean? `counter:\;`

Comment: @Pacane sorry I copied that part of the code from the question, which originally contained a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random number = new Random();
int n;
int min=1000;
int max=0;

for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
{
    n= number.Next(0,1000);

    if (n>max)
    {
        max=n;
    }

    if (n<min)
    {
        min=n;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(n);
}

Console.WriteLine("max:"+max);
Console.WriteLine("min:"+min);
```